# Unable to set up rhino debugger as a project in my IDE

Tags: ide, open-source, project, rhino

I am trying to tweak Rhino debugger work with my servlet so I downloaded the sources and for some reason I having some difficulties to set up the project properly in my IDE (intellij).

I have tried to add both the SRC and the Jar file but it seem like there is an *.internal.* package that get in the way.

For example:
Global that somewhere along the inheritance chain extends from sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptableObject

But who ever is using Global is expecting org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.

When I build the code using ant, it works fine so I am guessing it is something that I am missing..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that IntelliJ was modifying the imports when loading the project.

and the imports got mixed up between the 
org.mozilla.javascript... 
and sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptableObject

Creating a new project with the whole downloaded zip fixed the problem and gave the right source the was loaded